# LWC can't call apex with large body size > 3 Mb

Tags: lightning-web-components, upload

I am getting `Error: Received exception event aura:systemError from server` somewhere inside of aura_prod.js when call apex with large body (>3Mb).

```
import upload from '@salesforce/apex/Upload.upload';
export default class UploadSample extends LightningElement {
    handleUpload() {
        upload({ data: {}}) /* large body */
    }
}
```

It works fine with data less than 3 Mb. How to resolve my issue to be able send larger body ?

Comment: Would you mind uploading the apex code? Is the method you are calling cacheable?

Comment: My guess would be that you're running into the 6 MB heap limit on the Apex side. Whatever you send into Apex, you'll need at least that much to deserialize (or make a copy when you stick it into, say, an `Attachment`). 3+ MB * 2 > 6 MB

Comment: Are you trying to upload files to apex?

Comment: Yes, I try to upload file. I call apex with file data in base64 format

Comment: Apex is not being called at all. UI throws that error if body is large